# backward elimination in logistic regression using R

Tags: r, regression

I am running a logistic regression in R and doing "backward elimination" inorder to get my final model:

```
FulMod2 <- glm(surv~as.factor(tdate)+as.factor(tdate)+as.factor(sline)+as.factor(pgf)
                                    +as.factor(weight5)+as.factor(backfat5)+as.factor(srect2)
                                    +as.factor(bcs)+as.factor(loco3)+as.factor(fear3)
                                    +as.factor(teats)+as.factor(preudder)+as.factor(postudder)
                                    +as.factor(colos)+as.factor(tb5) +as.factor(respon3)
                                    +as.factor(feed5)+as.factor(bwt5)+as.factor(sex)
                                    +as.factor(fos2)+as.factor(gest3)+as.factor(int3),
                                    family=binomial(link="logit"),data=sof)
```

When trying to run the backward elimination script:

```
step(FulMod2,direction="backward",trace=FALSE)
```

I got this error message:

```
Error in step(FulMod2, direction = "backward", trace = FALSE) : 
  number of rows in use has changed: remove missing values?
```

This is the second model that I am running using the backward elimination function. The first model was fine when I did backward elimination to get my final model.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Baz

Comment: From `?step`: **Warning** The model fitting must apply the models to the same dataset. This may be a problem if there are missing values and R's default of na.action = na.omit is used. We suggest you remove the missing values first. You could look at `?complete.cases` to identify complete and incomplete cases in `sof`.

Comment: @BenBarnes, Thanks for your help. I have 9000 records and after applying "complete.cases", it has now dropped to 8000. I am just thinking if that is far too many to lose? Anyway, thanks once again!

Comment: On another note, if your predictors correspond to the rest of the columns in `sof`, then you can use the `.` operator for `?formula` to "specify all columns not otherwise named in the model. So something like `glm(surv ~ ., data  sof, family = binomial(link = "logit"))`. You'll want to make all of the classes `as.factor()` beforehand. Also, your first two predictors `as.factor(tdate)+as.factor(tdate)` seem identical. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Chase, Thanks for that. Regarding the first two predictors as.factor(tdate)+as.factor(tdate), it was not intentional!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to successfully run `step()` on your model for backwards selection, you should remove the cases in `sof` with missing data in the variables you are testing.

```
myForm <- as.formula(surv~
  as.factor(tdate)+as.factor(tdate)+as.factor(sline)+as.factor(pgf)
  +as.factor(weight5)+as.factor(backfat5)+as.factor(srect2)
  +as.factor(bcs)+as.factor(loco3)+as.factor(fear3)
  +as.factor(teats)+as.factor(preudder)+as.factor(postudder)
  +as.factor(colos)+as.factor(tb5) +as.factor(respon3)
  +as.factor(feed5)+as.factor(bwt5)+as.factor(sex)
  +as.factor(fos2)+as.factor(gest3)+as.factor(int3))

sofNoMis <- sof[which(complete.cases(sof[,all.vars(myForm)])),]

FulMod2 <- glm(myForm,family=binomial(link="logit"),data=sofNoMis)

step(FulMod2,direction="backward",trace=FALSE)
```

In your comment, you mentioned that 1 out of 9 cases has missing data. However, I recommend checking that again with the above code, in case some of that missingness corresponded to variables not included in `FulMod2`. If you still have many incomplete cases, you might want to decide *a priori* if you can eliminate some of the variables with high missingness.

Comment: I ran the model as you suggested above and gave me 8000 from 9000 records. Almost all predictors with high missing values are in the full model. Thanks!